# Run java from command line with non matching folder structure and package name

Tags: java, command-line, java-package

> Java requires no correlation between package names and source code
>   file structure. But most IDE's require sub-folder for each part of the
>   package name.

Is the above statement true?

To try this out, I have written a simple class in `~/Temp` folder.

```
package com.gnrcs.lab;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String... args) {
        System.out.println("Homo Sapiens");
    }
}
```

Then from command line,

```
~$ cd ~/Temp/
~$ javac Main.java // it does produce a Main.class file in ~/Temp
~$ java Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
~$ java com.gnrcs.lab.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class com.gnrcs.lab.Main
~$ java -cp . com.gnrcs.lab.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class com.gnrcs.lab.Main
```

What did I do wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Rob I tried this one too. Updated my question to add the result.

Comment: Does your classpath have "." in it? use the -cp option for java. For example: "java -cp . com.gnrcs.lab.Main"

Comment: @Dakoda I don't get it. Note that, there is no such folder structure, `com\gnrcs\lab`. Both `.java` and `.class` file are in same folder, `~/Temp`. Tried `-cp` options too.

Comment: Java itself (JDK) doesn't require correct structure to compile _source_ files but does require it to execute _class_ (bytecode) files. It's less confusing to be consistent for both and that's why IDEs do so.

Answer (score 3):

One result of using packages is that the bytecode of a class or interface must appear in a directory structure that matches its package name. If you do not put your bytecode in the proper directory structure, the compiler or the JVM will be unable to find your classes. The compiled bytecode file must appear in a directory structure on your file system that matches the package name. For example, a `.class` file for any class or interface in the `com.gnrcs.lab` package must appear in a directory structure matching `\com\gnrcs\lab\` . You can either create this directory structure yourself or use the `-d` flag during compilation and the compiler will create the necessary directory structure for you and place the bytecode in that directory.

To run the program you need to add `-classpath` flag while executing `java`.
Example: if you are in your Temp directory then you can use `java -classpath .\ com.gnrcs.lab.Main`.

In simple terms do the following:

1. `javac -d .\ Main.java`. This will create directory according to your package name and place the bytecode in that directory. In your case, `~/Temp/com/gnrcs/lab/Main.class`.
2. `java -classpath .\ com.gnrcs.lab.Main`. You must give fully qualified name here. You can also use `-cp` flag as shortcut for `-classpath`.

(Note: improvise for linux machine)

Comment: You don't need to specify classpath of `.` because that's the default (unless env var CLASSPATH is set to something else). Otherwise concur.