How to solve the issue resulting in output of the error message "class not found wrong class name"?
I have the following Java code in a file:
package hello_project;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");

    }
}

The code works when I run:
java Hello

But the code doesn't work when I use:
javac Hello.java
java Hello

The error message is:
class not found wrong class name


https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640119/330457

> type Hello.java
package hello_project;
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}

> javac -d . Hello.java

> dir hello_project
 ...

 Directory of C:\...\hello_project

06/14/2024  02:12 PM    <DIR>          .
06/14/2024  02:12 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/14/2024  02:12 PM               429 Hello.class
               1 File(s)            429 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  15,829,270,528 bytes free

> java -cp . hello_project.Hello
Hello world


Please include an explanation, don't expect that this is sufficient for someone to understand what the problem is.
